# ArcGIS Online hub, how to get the full list of ALL cities sub-domain

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-hub

ArcGIS Online hub, how to get the full list of ALL cities sub-domain

Now I know 3 city:

By use /data.json, I can get all dataset for that city.

City of Raleigh

https://data-ral.opendata.arcgis.com/data.json

city of los angeles

https://geohub.lacity.org/data.json

Spokane County WA

https://data-ral.opendata.arcgis.com/data.json

I want more city, I want a full list of all city sub-domain

If I have that full list, I can use below URL to get any cities any dataset.

https://{city-subdomain}.opendata.arcgis.com/data.json

Comment: This might be best asked direct to Esri, at least first to determine whether reproducing this list is within their terms of use

Comment: I’ve never seen such a list. If one exists, it’s only because someone has went to the trouble to make it. Not that Esri provides it. I should point out there’s nothing stopping anyone have registering whatever domain they want with open data. I bring that up as how can you be sure that given a city name, it’s authorative without vetting the website first?

Answer (score 1):

I have collect over 1000+ arcgis server list here,

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/418/arcgis-list-1000-organization

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/764/arcgis-1000-organization

Now I have collect 60+ of {city-sub-domain}.opendata.arcgis.com
geohub.arcgis.com/xxx
hub.arcgis.com/xxx

ESRI should maintain this full list, but they have not done yet, 
I end up do myself to create such list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, socrata open data have a full list of domain (233 city county state, etc...)

Here is working sample:

https://transparentgov.net/cleargov1/410/socrata-list-230-organization

In theory, ESRI should (if they have NOT yet) create a FULL list of sub-domain just like what socrata open data did.

Why?   you see, any city, county are sub-domain of {city-sub-domain}.opendata.arcgis.com

or hub.arcgis.com/{city-sub-domain}::{layer-name-id}

both url-format above are inter-changeable